# How to clear Navigation Stack on Windows phone using Xamarin Forms

Tags: windows, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am facing a problem with the Navigation Stack on Windows phone. I have a Main Menu Page which is root page in Navigation stack, from there I navigate to Page A --> Page B --> Page C.

Now on Page C, I have a button for Main Menu Page. Once Main Menu Page appears, user can not go back to Page C by using device back button. Navigation.popToRootAsync is not working in Windows phone. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Coincidentally, I recently fixed the `PopToRootAsync` [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31809) and it should be resolved in the 2.3.1 prerelease.

Update: the 2.3.1 prerelease is now available.